# How to know in which swf user clicks?

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4, flash

I use Flex 4 for writing swf part of my application... So I have some swf files loaded in container, and what I need is allow to change that swf by clicking in it...

How can I detect in which swf user clicks?

Answer (score 1):

The display component that you're using to load the swfs will trigger events that you can listen for. Try `mySwfLoader.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onMySwfLoaderClick);`

Alternately, you can add your listener to the container that contains all the loaded swfs and check the current target of the event when it's triggered.